# Cómo sacar sólo los EAM de este CSV PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Estoy trabajando con un CSV con PHP, pero no sé bien cómo sacar lo que yo quiero. Ahora mismo el CSV lo leo así:

```
 while(!feof($archivo)){

    $datosCSV=fgetcsv($archivo); //Leo datos con CSV

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($datosCSV);
    echo "</pre>";
        
 }
```

y me devuelve esto:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "eam;nombre"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "1;DECODIFICADOR ENGEL RS8100Y"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(50) "3;RELOJ DEPORTIVO CON GPS GARMIN INSTINCT SOLAR AM"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(42) "6;RELOJ DEPORTIVO CON GPS GARMIN FORERUNNE"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(42) "8;PORT�TIL ASUS ROG STRIX G15 G512LW-HN069"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(40) "9;PORT�TIL ASUS ROG ZEPHYRUS G14 GA401IU"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "10;LAS TINIEBLAS Y EL ALBA"
}
bool(false)

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Como veis, lo que me devuelve no está muy correcto. Para empezar, quiero quitar el primer array, que son los campos. Para continuar, quiero coger sólo los eam (el id), no me hace falta el resto. Y, por otro lado, tanto el bool (false) como el warning me viene de que me está pillando una fila en blanco imagino y no sé cómo quitar eso. Básicamente quiero acabar teniendo un array sólo con los eam, para luego poder comparar con los eam que ya tengo del MySQL.
He intentado muchas cosas, pero no acabo de dar con la tecla. Para quitar los campos, por ejemplo, he intentado (entre otras cosas, que ya no recuerdo porque intenté hacer esto con Node.js pero me resultó más difícil y volví a PHP) usar array_shift() tanto dentro como fuera del array, y me devolvía arrays vacíos (no sé por qué).

ACTUALIZACIÓN 1:
He sido capaz de quitar tanto el espacio en blanco de abajo como la cabecera, y quedarme con las líneas que tienen el contenido. El problema que tengo ahora es que cuando intento quedarme con el eam, con este código:

```
$arrayCSVId=array();

while(!feof($archivo)){

    $linea=fgets($archivo); //Leo datos con CSV
    $arrayLineas=explode(";", $linea);

    if(!empty($arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito cuando el eam esté vacío
        foreach ($arrayLineas as $key => $value) {
        // var_dump($value);
           $arrayCSVId[]=$value[0][0];
        }
      
    }   
 }

 echo "<pre>";
 var_dump($arrayCSVId);
 echo "</pre>";
```

lo que me devuelve es:

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "D"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "R"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "R"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "P"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "9"
  [9]=>
  string(1) "P"
  [10]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [11]=>
  string(1) "L"
}
```

No pillo porque me devuelve el primer carácter de cada campo, en vez de devolverme sólo los eam (los nº), que es lo que yo quiero.

ACTUALIZACIÓN 2.

Al hacer var_dump($value), puedo ver que el valor de $value, dentro del foreach que recorre $arrayLineas, es de:

```
string(1) "1"
string(29) "DECODIFICADOR ENGEL RS8100Y
"
string(1) "3"
string(50) "RELOJ DEPORTIVO CON GPS GARMIN INSTINCT SOLAR AM
"
string(1) "6"
string(42) "RELOJ DEPORTIVO CON GPS GARMIN FORERUNNE
"
string(1) "8"
string(42) "PORT�TIL ASUS ROG STRIX G15 G512LW-HN069
"
string(1) "9"
string(40) "PORT�TIL ASUS ROG ZEPHYRUS G14 GA401IU
"
string(2) "10"
string(25) "LAS TINIEBLAS Y EL ALBA
"
```

Por tanto, ahora ya comprendo por qué al coger $value[0] me saca un nº, y una letra, un nº y una letra y así. Lo que no sé ahora es cómo coger sólo los que son nº y desechar los títulos.

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: No necesitas el ciclo, simplemente el elemento cero (eam) `$arrayCSVId[]=$arrayLineas[0];` con un solo índice, porque el segundo `[0]` es lo que hace que tome solo el primer caracter.

Comment: foreach ($arrayLineas as $key => $value) {
        // var_dump($value);
           $arrayCSVId[]=$value[0];
        } Con este código me pilla también sólo el primer carácter, no sé por qué.

Comment: Insisto, no necesitas el ciclo, solo asignar la variable. El `var_dump()` te muestra un solo valor y el `[0]` hace que tome solo el primer caracter.